# How do I upgrade a Tezos node?

Tags: node

I used to run a full node, but then it somehow got tangled up and is now no longer downloading new blocks. I suspect that it has something to do with me not keeping it updated. Could someone tell me the commands that I need to use in order to get the newest update?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
git checkout mainnet && git pull && make build-deps && eval $(opam env) && make
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `docker` and run the latest image for the network you want

Comment: Is there documentation for this?

Comment: The official docker imager are located here: https://hub.docker.com/r/tezos/tezos/

If you search for docker on the official docs site you can find some information, but I'll admit it's not that great a resource for it. https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/search.html?q=docker&check_keywords=yes&area=default

This gist provides a better overview imho: https://gist.github.com/sirneb/8419e41aea4f2d5770555301006cea20