# How do I vote for a proposal?

Tags: voting

When I was preparing to vote, I had trouble finding the commands to vote on the proposals. I'm on the latest mainnet branch and also didn't find the relevant commands there.

Can someone provide a tutorial on how to vote for a proposal?

Comment: If you don’t know how to update your node check this question https://tezos.stackexchange.com/q/16/118

Comment: Related: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/829/how-to-vote-in-the-exploration-period

Answer (score 2):

The basic commands and explanations about voting are offered directly on [the official documentation page](https://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/voting.html).

Basically to summarize during a *proposal period* you van upvote one or more proposals with

```
tezos-client submit proposals for <delegate> <proposal1> <proposal2> ...
```

And during a voting period the tezos client command to submit your ballot is

```
tezos-client submit ballot for <delegate> <proposal> <yay|nay|pass>
```

Comment: But when I executed this command, there was no such parameter in reality.

Comment: tezos-client submit ballot for
Disclaimer:
  The  Tezos  network  is  a  new  blockchain technology.
  Users are  solely responsible  for any risks associated
  with usage of the Tezos network.  Users should do their
  own  research to determine  if Tezos is the appropriate
  platform for their needs and should apply judgement and
  care in their network interactions.

Error:
  Unrecognized command.
  Try using the man command to get more information.

Comment: Did you read the doc ? I edited my answer to make it even more clear but the full info is available in the link to the official doc

Comment: Yes, I read the document very carefully, voting is not in the main chain? But in the test chain?

Comment: @Sasuke voting is happening now on mainnet. We are in the proposing phase currently

Comment: Why can't I find the command?

Comment: @Sasuke which command. Please be specific as your other comments are difficult to parse

Comment: tezos-client submit ballot for <delegate> <proposal> <yay|nay|pass>
I can't find this command

Comment: I updated the latest main network branch and did not view the voting parameters.

Comment: @Sasuke i see it so it means you did not update to the latest client.

Comment: How can I check if it is the latest branch?

Comment: @Sasuke check your commit hash vs the latest on gitlab

Comment: Can this chat box add screenshots?

Comment: @Sasuke this is not meant to chat. Go to TG to continue this conversation if you cannot follow instructions

Comment: Yes, I don’t quite understand the process. Can you provide your telegram?

Comment: @Sasuke go to the mainchan buddy

Comment: what is mainchan?

Comment: I have updated the mainnet, but I still don't have the above command.

Comment: @Sasuke sorry you must have done something incorrectly then. At any rate this is the answer. If you have further question please use various support channels available (telegram, riot, slack) which are available. You can reference this question but this is not chatbox so better continue your questions to the community elsewhere. Hope you understand.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91164/discussion-on-answer-by-ezy-how-do-i-vote-for-a-proposal).