# How to vote in the exploration period?

Tags: baking, voting

I voted for one proposal but am now trying to find the command to vote for the proposal that came through. Can anybody help?

Comment: [This proposal?](https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/athens-proposals-injected.html)

Comment: Related: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/785/how-do-i-vote-for-a-proposal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ ./tezos-client show voting period
Current period: "testing_vote"
Blocks remaining until end of period: 32678
Current proposal: Pt24m4xiPbLDhVgVfABUjirbmda3yohdN82Sp9FeuAXJ4eV9otd
Ballots: { "yay": 2716, "nay": 0, "pass": 0 }
Current participation 5.09%, necessary quorum 80.00%
Current in favor 2716, needed supermajority 2172

$ ./tezos-client submit ballot for <PKH_alias> <hash_of_proposal> <yay|nay|pass>
```

Replace <PKH_alias> with your wallet address alias, replace <hash_of_proposal> with the actual hash, noted in the block above, and then the actual string 'yay' or 'nay' or 'pass'.

More information available on nomadic-labs site

https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/category/announcements.html

And on obsidian one

https://medium.com/@obsidian.systems/voting-on-tezos-with-your-ledger-nano-s-8d75f8c1f076

Comment: @Argonau7 Don't forget to mark the answer as solved!

Comment: yes, done it! Sorry, wasnt familiar with the process!